# Change the z index of flash content

Tags: html, css, flash

Basically my problem is the site I am working on has a horizontal drop down menu and I am implementing a flash chart on the page.

When you hover over the menu the items drop down behind the flash chart and are unclickable. Can I get around this somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you set the wmode to transparent for your flash content.

Comment: For those wondering how to do it: Just add this to your Flash object parameters: <param name="wmode" value="transparent">

Answer (score 3):

[bgiframe](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) is a jquery plugin that will allow you to do what you are asking; You can do this without jquery (obviously), but the plugin makes it really simple.  Technique is basically to add an IFrame around the content you want to show over top of the flash (this also works for hovering content over dropdown lists).

Answer (score 0):

@Fábio Antunes - Who is still wondering here is an example:

```
   <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/s...rsion=6,0,29,0" width="192" height="298">
          <param name="movie" value="flash/template2.swf">
          <param name="quality" value="high">
          <embed wmode="transparent"> <!--THIS IS NECESSARY TOO-->
          <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
          <embed src="flash/template2.swf" width="192" height="298" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"></embed>
        </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the wmode to transparent/opaque however, won't work if you are implementing an accessible site (which is now a government law).  Setting the wmode to transparent/opque will fix the issue of overlay, but will create more issues with regards to accessibility as you can't tab into the flash content, sometimes you can tab into it once, but as you cycle, you won't be able to tab into it again...