# How to show HTML elements over flash elements?

Tags: html, flash

When i create a menu, the dropdowns go behind the flash element. But in some sites, like Digg,  it is shown above. z-index is of no use !

How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712476/change-the-z-index-of-flash-content

Comment: WARNING: wmode="transparent" is the answer, but it comes with a big performance hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old site I worked on had this problem.  I fixed it by adding a transparent value/wmode param.

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```